# How does the Fleeca heist affect the Loyalty challenge?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

In GTA Online there are a few heist challenges you can complete for some bonus cash. One of these challenges is the Loyalty challenge. It requires you to complete every heist with the same team.

How does the Fleeca heist affect this? Unlike the other heists it can only be done with two people. Does it even count towards this challenge?

Answer (score 1):

Since i finished all the elite challenges yesterday, but didn't do the fleeca job with the same guy (picked a random I've never met), i can say with a probability of 99,9% that the fleeca job does not count into the heist challenges.

Answer (score 1):

It seems many have completed all the heists and still didn't get the "Loyalty" bonus until they redid the Fleeca mission again with one of their team members they did the other heists with and then it was counted. Could be a bug.

You can read about it more in the [Rockstar Support Forums](https://support.rockstargames.com/hc/communities/public/questions/203216967-GTA-Online-Loyalty-Challenge-Problems)

Comment: Hmm, thanks for that. Doesn't seem like there is a solid answer in there though.

Answer (score 0):

I have done my loyalty challenge and someone from my crew for the rest of the heists was with me in my Fleeca. I don't think it counts but just in case: have someone that you're going to bring to the rest of your heists.